# GCC flag to allocate more memory than needed?

Tags: c, gcc, g++, allocation, flags

When adding -ggdb3 flag it seems like compiler allocates more memory then it even needs for some objects and it may prevent in some cases from segmentation faults when dealing with out of memory space. Debugger puts more on the stack, so I'm less likely to overwrite something important. Is there a gcc flag covering such allocation that I would not have to enable debugging information flags at all?

Comment: If your program is causing segmentation faults with certain compiler flags, it means it has bugs and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just not the way to go. There are specific tools to check for incorrect usage of memory, probably the most popular one would be valgrind. You might want to get yourself familiar with it and use it on your code.

Comment: Do you search for tools like valgrind or efence?

Answer (score 1):

Its not probably what you are asking for. But you can use mcheck, see following:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html